# How are the nodes/units in the output layer of NN assigned to the classes?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

I am learning deep Learning and I keep wondering how are the nodes/units in the output layer of NN assigned to the classes because we dont usually indicate manually which neuron/node to represent which class label? For eg, for MNIST dataset (10 digits), if I have output layer of 10 units, is the first neuron necessarily the digit-0 or it takes on the first digit it sees? How will the neurons arrange for the MNSIT classifier NN? in ascending order? Does my question make sense?

Comment: This is defined by the labels, as the neurons have to produce similar output to the one-hot encoded version of your labels.

Comment: Thank you Dr. Snoopy. Yes I agree they are defined by the labels. But how are they arranged? The first neuron is for digit-0, the second neuron for digit-1 ... etc ? or not necessarily?

Comment: You can directly look at the integer labels of the MNIST dataset and their one-hot encoded version to answer your question. The labels are defined by the dataset.